# Displaying a platform exception error in alertdialog or snackbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i need help trying to display a flutter error message (flutter: PlatformException(ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, The email address is already in use by another account., null)) into a string i can use in alertdialog or snackbar, but i need to be able to change the string dependent on the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
  final auth = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
  await auth.signIn();
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  await PlatformExceptionAlertDialog(
    title: 'The email address is already in use by another account.',
    exception: e,
  ).show(context);
}
```